# Pegar último ID gerado no insert, retornar para função ajax e enviar para outra página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache-cordova

Estou fazendo um programa e na primeira página insiro uma série de valores digitados pelo usuário no banco e gero um `id`. Após isso gostaria de retornar o valor para a função AJAX e redirecionar para outra página passando esse `id` como parâmetro. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Inserindo na tabela (ao invés de retornar `1` na variável `cadastro`, gostaria de retornar o código do registro inserido):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO incidente (titulo, descricao, anonimo, tipo, foto)';
$sql .= 'VALUES (:titulo, :descricao, :anonimo, :tipo, :foto)' ;

try {

$recebeConexao = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$recebeConexao->bindParam(':titulo', $_POST['titulo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':descricao', $_POST['descricao'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':anonimo', $_POST['anonimo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':tipo', $_POST['tipo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':foto', $_POST['img'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$recebeConexao->execute();

if($recebeConexao == true){
    $cadastro = 1;
}else{
    $cadastro = 0;
}

} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "Erro inserção";
}

echo (json_encode($cadastro));

?>
```

Função AJAX (Gostaria de chamar a outra página enviando o valor do `id`):

```
function enviar(){
    var formula = $('#formCliente').serialize();
    var img = document.getElementById('smallImage').innerHTML;

$.ajax({

type:'POST',
data:formula,

url:'http://ip/connect/www/criar_incidente_camera.php',

success: function(data){

    if(data == '' || data == 0){
        alert('Usuário ou senha incorreto' + data);   
        window.location = "";
    }

    if(data == 1){
        alert('Seja Bem-vindo!' + data); 
        window.location.href = "mapa_incidente.html";   
    } else {
        alert('outro' + data); 
    }

}
```

Obrigada pela atenção!

Comment: Qual o banco de dados?

Comment: já tentou $pdo->lastInsertId();

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função lastInsertId() nativa do PDO

No PHP:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO incidente (titulo, descricao, anonimo, tipo, foto)';
$sql .= 'VALUES (:titulo, :descricao, :anonimo, :tipo, :foto)' ;

$retorno = array(
    'cadastro' => 0,
    'id' => NULL,
    'erro' => NULL
);
try {

$recebeConexao = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$recebeConexao->bindParam(':titulo', $_POST['titulo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':descricao', $_POST['descricao'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':anonimo', $_POST['anonimo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':tipo', $_POST['tipo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':foto', $_POST['img'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$recebeConexao->execute();

if($recebeConexao == true){
    $retorno['cadastro'] = 1;
}

} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $retorno['erro'] = "Erro inserção";
}

echo (json_encode($retorno));

?>
```

No Javascript:

```
function enviar(){
    var formula = $('#formCliente').serialize();
    var img = document.getElementById('smallImage').innerHTML;

$.ajax({

type:'POST',
data:formula,
dataType: 'json',

url:'http://ip/connect/www/criar_incidente_camera.php',

success: function(data){

    if(data.cadastro == 0){
        alert(data.erro);   
        window.location = "";
    }else if(data.cadastro == 1){
        alert('Seja Bem-vindo!'); 
        window.location.href = "mapa_incidente.html?id="+ data.id;   
    } else {
        alert(data); 
    }

}
```

Fiz mais ou menos, oque entendi que queria, espero ter ajudado.